# Why C code giving segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I just want to know why this piece of code giving me segfault.

```
if(argc < 2){
    printf("\n Please mention the file name");
    exit(1);
}
FILE* fp;
if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL){
    printf("\n can't open file");
    exit(1);
}
char* str;
fgets(str,80,fp);
printf("\n this is the output %s",str);
```

If I declare str as char str[100],then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char* str;` declares a pointer to char, but doesn't reserve any space for the characters themselves.  Also since you haven't initialized it, it is pointing at some random place in memory.

Then `fgets(str, 80, fp)` says to take 80 characters from the file and store them starting at the pointed location.  Since (most likely) your program doesn't own that location, you get a segfault.

`char str[100];` reserves space for 100 characters on the stack as an array, and you can use `str` as a pointer to the start of this array.  Your program is allowed to do whatver it wants with this memory so there is no segfault when you do `fgets`.  Note that if your array is too short, then you may still have problems, though not necessarily segfaults.

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating any memory; you're just declaring a `char *`. Either `char str[100]` will work, or:

```
char *str = malloc(100);
```

That will allocate memory for your string. Otherwise, you're just reading from `fgets()` into memory that isn't yours, and causing a segmentation fault.

If you do this, make sure to call `free()` on it after you're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

`char* str` is an uninitialized pointer.  `fgets` writes to the memory pointed to by this pointer, which can be anywhere.  Declaring actual storage with `str[100]` provides 100 bytes of valid memory to write.